# How do I make my screenshots save when dragging into a web application

Tags: macos, finder, screen-capture

I'm using a virtual web app where it has a feature that makes it so you can drag images and send it to someone. On macOS 10.13, this routine was me screenshotting what I needed, an automatic save to a folder I set, opening Finder to the folder, then dragging the image to the app.

On macOS 12, this routine changed. You run the <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> keybind to screenshot, and it will appear in the lower right of your screen for 3 seconds and then disappear. **When I "prematurely" drag it into the web app and send it off, I don't see it in finder**. When I let it drag into a folder, I have to wait 3 seconds for it to go in a folder or send it off by swiping it, and then drag it to the web app.

How do I make it so when I drag the image in the lower left into a web app, the image will also save to Finder?

Comment: Use Cmd shift 5 & switch off in options. On phone so real answer later. I think there’s an existing question somewhere on here

Comment: @Tetsujin There's no option to save it even when dragging it

Comment: Switch off the preview, then it will drag

Comment: I'd like it so I can drag the thumbnail into an app, then even after the image will save. When you tell me to "switch off the preview" (actually show floating thumbnail), this exhibits the behavior I had in 10.13 and completely defeats the point of the time-saver by dragging the thumbnail to an app.